I migrated my javascript client to another domain and now cross site call to php api are not sharing the same php session
For some time now I had to endpoint :

https://client.a.com => a javascript client (nuxt)
https:/api.a.com => PHP api (slim framework)

To make those work tohgether I needed a shared Php session. So for that I setted up everything like this :

call from the client (using axios) areconfigurated with withCredentials = true
response headers from the api were configurated like this :

Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://client.a.com
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Origin, Authorization
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS

And it worked well.
Now, I want to move client from https://client.a.com to https://b.com
So I didn't change a thing in the client, but I change the api headers response to
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://b.com
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Origin, Authorization
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS

And it does not work at all.
Everytime I send a new request from the client to the api it is a new PHP session.
Any idea what would be the trick, if there is one ?
Cheers <3

Session cookies can be shared between subdomains, with the right configuration - presumably that's what has been happening up to now. But you can't share sessions across entirely different root domains. Really, if you are designing an app with a totally separate client-side, it should be architected in a stateless way so that it doesn't require the use of sessions in the first place anyway. Either stick with your subdomains, or rethink your software architecture.

Ok, so the easiest way for me, will be to go down the following route :
client.a.com => b.com AND api.a.com => api.b.com
Would this work ?

As long as your session cookies cover the root domain, so that they can be shared between the subdomains too, then I think it would work, yes. Should be easy to enough for you to test it out, I expect.

Ok, let's go I'll try that then.

And it works like that ...
So okay, not what I planned but it is the better way haha :-)
Thank you mate.

Session cookies can be shared between subdomains, with the right configuration - presumably that's what has been happening up to now. But you can't share sessions across entirely different root domains.
If you want to move the front-end to a new domain, e.g. b.com, without redesigning your software more substantially, a simple solution would be to move the backend to a subdomain of b.com, e.g. api.b.com.

P.S. Longer-term: Ideally if you are designing an app with a totally separate client front-end and an API backend, it should be architected in a more stateless way so that it doesn't require the use of sessions in the first place.

And just to add a little bit about the "P.S".
I know it should be stateless, but in the case of this app, data that are shared are very very sensitive. And so there should be no way for a malicious person to take the session of another user. But I need to use oAuth2 calls in my app (we are talking to other apis)... and I didn't want any Access Token to be readable even if someone can access my browser. So the only way to hide this token was to put it in the PHP Session. And then I have plenty of security around the PHP Session. And yup. That's it.

@stadja the token could have still been stored server-side securely, without sessions, and still associated to a particular application user. There are other ways to do that. But yeah I can see why you might have designed it that way.
